# Get caret's visual position with respect to window in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript

I have contenteditable div, and I need to show a dropdown just below the current position of the caret.

For instance, if I type 'foofoofoofoo' in my div, I need to show a dropdown just below the current position of the caret which is at the end of 'foofoofoofoo'. How do I determine this position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [library](https://github.com/ichord/Caret.js) worked like a charm.